# Object name 'Clean Up History' in use when trying to complete the maintenance plan wizard in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, maintenance, maintenance-plans

I am trying to create a maintenance plan on a instance running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (no CU's installed).

When completing the wizard I get the following error:

> The object name cannot be changed from
>   "{1E1746D3-B671-4799-8F61-7EE6117257C2}" to "Clean Up History" because
>   another object in the collection already uses that name. Use a
>   different name to resolve this error. 
>   ({1E1746D3-B671-4799-8F61-7EE6117257C2})

I've checked both `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps]` and `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]` and neither contain the name "Clean Up History".

The server is being backed up by Microsoft DPM. Could it be that DPM inserts a cleanup job somewhere that I don't see?

Comment: You mentioned sysjobsteps twice.  I assume that was a mistake?   Also, why don't you simply call the step something else; perhaps `Clean_Up_History`?

Comment: @MaxVernon Woops - corrected. It's the wizard who wants to use the name. I could do it all manually and get it working, but I'd like to know why I have a colliding object (and where I should find it).

Answer (score 2):

The job is "owned" by a maintenance plan in the following table, and I don't believe the names have to match. So you may want to check the following location:

```
SELECT name,id,description 
  FROM msdb..sysssispackages
  WHERE name = N'Clean Up History';
```

So you could rename that one, but it may cause problems later (some automated process may need to match on that name, or simply re-create it if it doesn't find it). So a much safer approach would be to use a different name for your own maintenance plan...

Comment: No results there either. I even installed integration services to see if it was a package, but nothing there.

Comment: @pauska and what happens if when you manually create your maintenance plan you use a different name?

Comment: It's not the maintenance plan name that collides, but a step. I can't choose the step name during the wizard. I can create manual plans with manual steps and name them whatever I want. I'm interested in finding out what object is holding the name "Clean Up History"

Comment: I forgot to add. Yes, I can add a clear history task with a different name manually and it works.

Comment: Without full access to your system I don't know that anyone here will be able to pinpoint the location of this mystery step.

Comment: I understand. I'm just looking for pointers for where to look.